# Button stays disabled after enabling it from thread until I focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a button that will start a background task. It is bound to a command that will change a property to disable it until the task is finished. The task will complete and change to property back in the continueWith.
The button will stay disabled until I click anywhere in the window.

Here is the code:

```
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
        Content="Run"/>
```

```
public bool IsRunning
{
      get => _IsRunning;
      set
      {
            if (_IsRunning == value)
            {
                  return;
            }

            _IsRunning = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
      }
}

private ICommand _StartCommand;
public ICommand StartCommand => _StartCommand ??
(_StartCommand = new RelayCommand(x =>
{
       IsRunning = true;

       var task = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));

       task.ContinueWith(t => { IsRunning = false; });

 }, x => !IsRunning));


public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Adding Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke() did not help as well.

I would like to understand what goes wrong and have a solution without code behind.

Thanks!

Comment: How does `IsRunning` is declared?

Comment: Also, does adding `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` to invalidate to command bindings.

Another option is setup `Binding` for `IsEnabled` property of `Button` to inversed `IsRunning` value and get rid of `CanExecute` predicate in `RelayCommand`

```cs
private ICommand _StartCommand;

public ICommand StartCommand => _StartCommand ??
                    (_StartCommand = new DelegateCommand(x =>
                    {
                        IsRunning = true;
                        var task = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
                        task.ContinueWith(t =>
                        {
                            IsRunning = false;
                        });
                    }));

private bool _isRunning;

public bool IsRunning
{
    get => _isRunning;
    set
    {
        _isRunning = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsRunning));
    }
}
```

The xaml declaration

```
<local:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="InverseBooleanConverter"/>
...
<Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Content="Run" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding IsRunning, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

`InverseBooleanConverter` declaration

```cs
[ValueConversion(typeof(bool), typeof(bool))]
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is bool boolValue ? !boolValue : Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the idea here is that we setup our command's `CanExecute` to return whether or not the command can execute (the example here is `!IsRunning`).

we know when the command's ability to execute has changed right (when we are literally setting `IsRunning` to a new value), so when this happens, we should raise `ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`, *because that's exactly what just happened*, the command's ability to execute has just changed.

lo and behold, part of databinding Button.Commands is WPF hooking up not only the Execute method we provide but also the `CanExecute` method, and WPF will re-evaluate `CanExecute` when `CanExecuteChanged` is raised.

everywhere right after `IsRunning` is set we'd want to raise `_StartCommand.CanExecuteChanged` by calling `Invoke` on it, which can only be done within `RelayCommand` itself because of the time-old rule in C# of `The event can only appear on left hand side of += or -=`, so i'd suggest adding a `protected void RaiseCanExecuteChanged` in the `RelayCommand` to do just that: `CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)`.